# Inputing data in OCaml toplevel runnin under Emacs

Tags: input, emacs, ocaml, tuareg, ocaml-toplevel

When interactively running the OCaml toplevel on Emacs (via the Tuareg mode), evaluation of expression which do input from the standard input channel does not finish.

For instance, when I enter the following expression in the `*ocaml-toplevel*` buffer and hit enter

```
let x = read_int ();;
```

and type some integer and hit `ENTER` to finish, evaluation is not finished as it was expected.

The following screenshot demonstrates the situation.

[image]

What is the proper way of doing input from the standard input channel in the OCaml toplevel buffer in Emacs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just type as usal an use
`M-x comint-send-input`
directly, so tuareg won't check for the terminating `;;`

edit: of course, you can define a keyboard shortcut for it, if you need it regularly; e.g

```
 (add-hook 'tuareg-interactive-mode-hook
  '(lambda ()
      (local-set-key (kbd "C-n") 'comint-send-input)))
```

Comment: Can this be configured, so that I do not have to use `M-x comint-send-input` for every input done in the toplevel?